# Spring Integration Outbound File Adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm kind of having issues on implementing certain functionality and I'm noticing some inconsistencies when I drop files.

1) When I drop multiple files, sometimes not all files get transferred to the correct directory.

2) Sometimes the service activator hits before the file transfer happens by the outbound adapter.

3) Sometimes it stalls with .moving.

a) So by looking at the code below, is it correctly setup?

b) How can i make sure the source files are deleted before the service activator hits.

c) Is the transactional code necessary?

```
<!-- Adapter for reading files in the incoming directory -->
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="incomingFileAdapter"
                                  channel="fileInputChannel"
                                  prevent-duplicates="false"
                                  scanner="recursiveDirectoryScanner"
                                  filename-regex="^.*\.(?i)(avi|divx|xvid|flv|f4v|mkv|m1v|m2v|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mp4|mov|vob|wmv|asf|ts|mxf)$"
                                  directory="${file.listener.path.incoming}">
    <int:poller id="filePoller" default="true" max-messages-per-poll="5" fixed-rate="5000">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="pseudoTransactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<!-- Adapter for writing files to the processed directory -->
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="processedFileAdapter"
                                   mode="REPLACE"
                                   channel="fileInputChannel"
                                   delete-source-files="true"
                                   auto-create-directory="true"
                                   order="1"
                                   directory-expression="@dynamicDirectoryGenerator.generateDirectory(payload)" />

<int:service-activator
        input-channel="fileInputChannel"
        output-channel="nullChannel"
        order="2"
        ref="fileInputActivator"
        method="processMessage"/>

<bean id="fileInputActivator" class="com.nfl.dm.shield.ingestion.file.activator.FileInputActivator" />
<bean id="recursiveDirectoryScanner" class="org.springframework.integration.file.RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner" />
<bean id="dynamicDirectoryGenerator" class="com.nfl.dm.shield.ingestion.file.dynamic.DynamicDirectoryGenerator" />
<bean id="pseudoTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager" />
```

Answer (score 1):

a) Since you don't have a declaration for `fileInputChannel`, it's a `DirectChanel` which means the messages will alternately go to the outbound adapter and service activator.

Declare it as a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` and each file will go to both subscribers (based on `order`).

b) It's not clear what you mean since you want to send the file to the service, why do you want it deleted before it gets there? If you do mean that then you can add a `<request-handler-advice-chain/>` to the file adapter with an [ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain). See the [retry-and-more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more) for an example of how to use that advice.

c) No, the pseudo transaction is not necessary since you are not taking any action on success or failure.

Comment: Hi Gary, forgot to copy/paste that.... I had pub/sub channel.  What is really throwing my code off is the following...

I need to make sure the following events are happening in this order...  
a) Drop file in source directory. 
b) Transfer file to output directory.
c) Delete file from source directory.
d) Hit the service activator. 
Is there a way I can do this?  Literally if I drop in a 800mb file, I need to make it wait until the transfer happens, the source deleted, and then the service activator hitting.

Comment: Yes; as I said in b) you can use a request handler advice on the file outbound adapter, to delete the original file before the message is sent to the service activator.

Comment: Also, when I drop multiple files, some don't transfer accordingly to the output directory, any idea why?

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to watch the message flow.

Comment: Thanks Gary, btw, is there a way I can convert the <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter to java config?

Comment: See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#d4e15193). In this case, the `MessageSource` `@Bean` would be a properly wired up `FileReadingMessageSource`.

Comment: Gary I'm a bit confused on the retry logic code.  Can we do a chat room for like 5 minutes please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82745/discussion-between-gary-russell-and-user1172490).